# Select rows with max value from groups grouped by two columns (PSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to select rows with max value from groups grouped by two columns.

```
shared_id    age_range   average_date
001          01-21       2016-10-25 22:00
001          01-21       2016-10-25 21:00
001          21-40       2016-10-25 20:00
001          21-40       2016-10-25 19:00
002          01-21       2016-10-25 18:00
002          01-21       2016-10-25 17:00
002          21-40       2016-10-25 16:00
002          21-40       2016-10-25 15:00
003          01-21       2016-10-25 14:00
003          01-21       2016-10-25 13:00
003          21-40       2016-10-25 12:00
003          21-40       2016-10-25 11:00
```

And the result should be:

```
shared_id    age_range   average_date
001          01-21       2016-10-25 22:00
001          21-40       2016-10-25 20:00
002          01-21       2016-10-25 18:00
002          21-40       2016-10-25 16:00
003          01-21       2016-10-25 14:00
003          21-40       2016-10-25 12:00
```

I tried to get result with `DISTINCT ON` and `max()` but got only many errors.

Comment: can you post the code you tried and the errors this looks to be a fairly straight forward group by with MAX() on average_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    share_id
    ,age_range
    ,MAX(average_date) as average_date
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    share_id
    ,age_range
```